# Blackberry app integration with compass application

Tags: blackberry, google-maps-mobile

Is there a way to launch the compass application in blackberry os7 programmatically?

Comment: you can launch another application using ApplicationManager class.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch any Application by using the [ApplicationManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html).

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launchApplication(Application);
```

In your case, it would likely be:

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launchApplication("net_rim_bb_compass");
```

Comment: cant i pass parameters to the application to open ccompass in direction i specify  like provide longitude latitude.. ? or angle ?

Comment: You only asked how to launch the compass, therefore my answer was correct. Launching it AND passing parameters is a whole new ball game!